# Solving Electric and Magnetic Fields for Charged Particle Path

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations, physics

I am using the Lorentz Force Equation and the electric-cross-magnetic field velocity equation] to solve for the $E$ and $B$ fields given the known path of a particle moving in 3D.

So with that I have the following equations where a and v are known:
[Lorentz Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL7fg.gif) and the
[E-cross-B Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuxHP.gif)

My question: Are these equations enough to solve for the $x, y, z$ components of $B$ and $E$?

----------Edit---------------

So this is actually being used as an analogy for the propagation of nano-scale self replicating cracks in 3D. In this analogy, the incoming tensile force is represented by the electric force, and the delamination is represented by the magnetic force.

So I have a parabaloid spiral shaped crack which will represent the motion of a charged particle. Since I know the shape/path I can directly get the position, velocity, and acceleration functions in each direction.

With that said, is there a way to use the two equations linked to find all components of the electric and magnetic fields?

Answer (score 1):

One interesting case when a charged particles is at rest initially in the crossed electric and magnetic fields, it moves in a cycloid.

See the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eOn5K9qZu4).

See also a detailed discussion in Chapter 2 of **Fundamentals of Plasma Physics** by *Bittencourt, J. A.* [here](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwizqZaS4uTNAhWBqZQKHdOIDF0QFgg5MAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9780387209753-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-110333-p25145278&usg=AFQjCNEuZT5BZvHNOikGh_UvyP4GNa6Ysw)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where the particle is moving in a straight line with constant velocity.  Then the magnetic field in the direction of that velocity has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if they are sufficient, but you could add [magnetostatic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostatics#Magnetostatics_as_a_special_case_of_Maxwell.27s_equations) if your magnetic field is constant over time, or instead [the general equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Maxwell.E2.80.93Faraday_equation) 
$$\nabla \times \overrightarrow{E} = -\frac{\partial \overrightarrow{B}}{\partial t}$$

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any insight on what to use if a.) both are non-constant or b.) E is constant with B changing over time?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what to say, because I believe case b) is somehow the general case, because when B is time-dependent, you pop out of magnetostatic. That said, maybe you could add some energy conservation, or use that E is conservative.

Comment: Furthermore, in case b) there may be some symmetries you could exploit, especially if your particle's path follows these symmetries (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampère%27s_circuital_law)